# Is there a away to get Berkshelf to stop uploading cookbooks to Chef Server?

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf

I'm using Chef Server to provision my vagrant box, and my Vagrantfile looks like this

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'CentOS-7.1-64'
  config.vm.box_url = 'https://github.com/holms/vagrant-centos7-box/releases/download/7.1.1503.001/CentOS-7.1.1503-x86_64-netboot.box'

  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest

  config.berkshelf.enabled = true
  config.berkshelf.berksfile_path = './Berksfile'

  config.vm.provision :chef_client do |chef|
    chef.provisioning_path = "/etc/chef"
    chef.chef_server_url = "https://api.opscode.com/organizations/myorg"
    chef.validation_key_path = ".chef/myorg-validator.pem"
    chef.validation_client_name = "myorg-validator"
    chef.node_name = "vagrant_dev"
    chef.add_role ENV['CHEF_ROLE']
    chef.environment = ENV['CHEF_ENV']
  end
end
```

Every time I provision my box, it re-uploads everything to the server

```
==> default: Uploading cookbooks to https://api.opscode.com/organizations/myorg
```

This usually takes a while. Is there a way for it to not upload the cookbooks if they already exist?

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, I usually use chef-solo or chef-zero locally, so I am not joining Vagrant boxes to my hosted chef account. When I run Vagrant in this fashion, Berkshelf still copies all my cookbooks to Vagrant.

I am not sure there's going to be an easy way to turn this behavior off, as it's one of the major functions of Berkshelf (beyond resolving dependencies, the major thing you want is to then *use* them).

Comment: @Martin Yeah, I'll just go with that for now. Thanks.